Calculate the volume section of sphere
Look at this picture.

Given a half of sphere with radius $r=2$. Let orange plane (as picture above) is parallel with bottom plane. Orange plane is disc with radius $r=\sqrt 2$. Find the volume section of half sphere in the above of orange plane.
I just only know the volume of half sphere, i.e.
$$V=\dfrac{2}{3}\pi r^3.$$
I confused to determine the volume of section half sphere in the above of orange plane because I don't have idea to compute many parts of half-sphere above the orange plane. Anyone can explain me how to compute it?

You may check out the formula for the volume of the spherical cap. To derive the formula without calculus, see here for example.

From Mengchun Zhang comment's, I try answer my question as below.
Given $r=2$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$, we have
\begin{align*}
&2hr=a^2+h^2\\
\iff & 4h=2+h^2\\
\iff & h^2-4h+2=0\\
\iff& h_{1,2} = \dfrac{4\pm \sqrt{8}}{2} = \dfrac{4\pm 2\sqrt{2}}{2} = 2\pm \sqrt{2}.
\end{align*}
Since $r=2$, $h=2+\sqrt{2}$ is not allowed. Now we have $h=2-\sqrt{2}$.
Using $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $h=2-\sqrt{2}$, we have
\begin{align}
V&=\frac{1}{6}\pi h (3a^2+h^2)\\
&= \frac{1}{6}\pi (2-\sqrt{2}) (3(\sqrt{2})^2+(2-\sqrt{2})^2)\\
&= \frac{1}{6}\pi (2-\sqrt{2}) (6+4-4\sqrt 2+2)\\
&= \frac{1}{6}\pi (2-\sqrt{2}) (12-4\sqrt 2)\\
&= \frac{1}{6}\pi (24-20\sqrt{2} +8 )\\
&= \frac{1}{6}\pi (32-20\sqrt{2})\\
&= \pi \left(\frac{16}{3}-\frac{10}{3}\sqrt{2}\right)\\
\end{align}
